# Ftp file upload- android

Tags: android, ftp, ftp-client

I am trying to upload a image file to ftp server. the connect and login are successful but the uplaod  always returns 550 access is denied.

this is my code below

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        int reply = 0;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File(lastImageName));
            Log.i("file_path", lastImageName);
            client.connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 21);
            reply = client.getReplyCode();
            Log.i("ftp_connect reply", reply + " "+client.getReplyString());
            boolean loginStatus = client.login("test", "test");
            Log.i("login_success??", loginStatus + " "+ client.getReplyString());
            client.pasv();
//          client.enterRemotePassiveMode();
            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            client.changeWorkingDirectory("abc");
            client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            boolean uploadstatus = client.storeFile("/abc", fis);
            // int uploadstatus2 = client.stor(lastImageName);
            String stringReply = client.getReplyString();
            Log.i("upload_success??", uploadstatus + " " + stringReply);

            client.logout();
            client.disconnect();
```

but wen i try to upload a file using fireFTP it works. I dont get that access is denied error.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why giving the file the same name as the directory where you want to put it in? But anyhow try to do without the / in /abc. By the way: you are not checking if the change of cwd is successfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this:

```
boolean uploadstatus = client.storeFile("/abc", fis);
```

with this:

```
boolean uploadstatus = client.storeFile("abc", fis);
```